# Where are the options for the Loop Cut and Slide?

Tags: interface

I'm a bit lost in the Blender 2.80 interface. I'm in edit mode trying to do a Loop Cut and Slide (although I'm having the same issue with other tools). Where are the options?

I'm selecting the edges in edit mode and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and I expect there would be settings/options somewhere, but I get nothing.

It's not in the <kbd>N</kbd> menu, nor in the "screwdriver & wrench" panel, nor anywhere else that I can see. I searched here and in the documentation but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: the last operation box is in the bottom left, if this is what you're looking for...

Comment: Also F9 after you complete the operation if you lose the parameters before your next operation (i.e. click away somewhere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last operation box is in the bottom left, just click to unfold:

[image]

Comment: Thanks again. The screen is so vast and there are so many interface elements that I missed it.